# Docusign API Not Returning LastLogin for User Endpoint

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm querying the [getUser](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/list/) API with queryParamaters (additional_info=true&login_status=true).

[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[accountID]/users?additional_info=true&login_status=true&lastLogin=true](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%5BaccountID%5D/users?additional_info=true&login_status=true&lastLogin=true)

I'm not getting the lastLogin data for all users under the account. Rest of the info is returned fine.

Also tried getting userinfo and the response still doesn't show the lastLogin data:
[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[accountID]/users/[userID]?additional_info=true&login_status=true&lastLogin=true](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%5BaccountID%5D/users/%5BuserID%5D?additional_info=true&login_status=true&lastLogin=true)

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a known issue and is currently looking into being fixed. This information should be available through the DocuSign Admin get user profile API, this is currently planned to be released by May 2021.

Comment: @GlorianaMarin Any update on that?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `additional_info: true` flag in order to get the `lastLogin` field in the result